# Bind Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top in Style

Tags: wpf, binding, attached-properties

I am trying to reflect a position from my view-model expressing the location of an object in my view by binding the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties in the style of the item view to appropriate properties in the view-model. However, the bindings do not seem to work.

For this minimal sample, I have simplified the structure so there only is one control `Thing` that is styled and templated:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace LocationBinding
{
    public class Thing : Control
    {
        static Thing()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Thing), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Thing)));
        }

        public Point Location {
            get {
                return new Point(70, 70);
            }
        }

        public double VPos {
            get {
                return 100;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, I have declared the style in the resource dictionary of the main window - a simple window with a canvas on it (my real project has this in `Themes\Generic.xaml`).  In its style, I am binding to property values of the control:

```
<Window x:Class="LocationBinding.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LocationBinding"
    Title="LocationBinding" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:Thing">
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="542"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Location.X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding VPos}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Thing">
                        <Ellipse Fill="ForestGreen" Width="30" Height="30"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas Name="cnv">

    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

The code-behind of the main window simply adds a `Thing` instance to the canvas:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace LocationBinding
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            cnv.Children.Add(new Thing());
        }
    }
}
```

The style is correctly applied, as evidenced by the `ZIndex` value (according to Snoop) and the correct template-based appearance of the control. However, `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` remain unset (and thus the `Thing` sticks in the top left corner of the canvas), even though according to threads such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708151/how-to-convert-x-y-position-to-canvas-left-top-properties-when-using-itemscontro) or [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a1a47227-ff4d-44d0-92c5-728ccc7ed53e/how-to-multibinding-canvasleft-in-itemscontrol?forum=wpf), `Property="Canvas.Left"` seems to be the correct syntax to refer to the attached property in a style.

I was first trying to bind `Canvas.Top` to `Location.Y` and replaced that with the `VPos` property in case the problem is related to binding to struct properties, but that does not seem to change anything, either.

**What am I missing; how can I bind `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` in my style to the coordinates from my `Thing.Location` property?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, *binding will search for property in DataContext* of control but `Location` is your control (*Thing*) property.

So you need to use `RelativeSource` with Mode set to `Self` to tell binding engine to search for property in control itself and not in DataContext of control:

```
<Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Location.X,
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```